# Sampling from known distribution in R

Tags: r

I am using the fitdistrplus package in R. So far I have identified the appropriate distribution (using the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fitdistrplus/vignettes/paper2JSS.pdf) and the 'groundbeef' data):

```
> library(fitdistrplus)
> data("groundbeef")
> str(groundbeef)
'data.frame':   254 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ serving: num  30 10 20 24 20 24 40 20 50 30 ...
> descdist(groundbeef$serving, boot = 1000)
summary statistics
------
min:  10   max:  200 
median:  79 
mean:  73.64567 
estimated sd:  35.88487 
estimated skewness:  0.7352745 
estimated kurtosis:  3.551384 
> fw<-fitdist(groundbeef$serving, "weibull")
> fg<-fitdist(groundbeef$serving, "gamma")
> fln<-fitdist(groundbeef$serving, "lnorm")
> gofstat(list(fw, fg, fln), fitnames = c("weibull", "gamma", "lnorm"))
Goodness-of-fit statistics
                               weibull     gamma     lnorm
Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic 0.1396646 0.1281246 0.1493090
Cramer-von Mises statistic   0.6840994 0.6934112 0.8277358
Anderson-Darling statistic   3.5736460 3.5660192 4.5436542

Goodness-of-fit criteria
                                weibull    gamma    lnorm
Aikake's Information Criterion 2514.449 2511.250 2526.639
Bayesian Information Criterion 2521.524 2518.325 2533.713
```

Based on this I could choose the gamma distribution to describe the data. What I would like to do now is to see how different sample sizes of the data affect the gof. For example, the current gof is based on 254 observations - how does the gof change if I am only using a random sample of 50 of those observations? At some point there must be a threshold where the gamma is no longer appropriate (i.e. a sample of 1 will not be best described by these distributions).
I have looked at [this](http://atomicules.co.uk/2013/08/06/Calculating-Sample-Size-for-Non-Normal-Distributions-Using-Bootstrapping-in-R.html) and it is more or less what I am hoping to do, except there is only one data-group (which is 'groundbeef$serving') and I am not interested in calculating power but tracking how the p-value changes as I use different sample sizes.

Comment: This seems more like a conceptual question about understanding GoF & N. I think it may be better suited for [stats.SE].

Comment: I actually want to know how to achieve this in R - how do I take samples of data (N), use bootstrapping and measure the gof using p values (with the idea that when I hit a nominated alpha the gof is no longer valid). Not looking for feedback on the approach. Hope that helps. Something similar to http://atomicules.co.uk/2013/08/06/Calculating-Sample-Size-for-Non-Normal-Distributions-Using-Bootstrapping-in-R.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Randomly sample size N 1000 times from the original dataset, test the goodness of fit for each random sample, see what the mean p value of the 1000 gof tests is.

```
df <- groundbeef

for (i in 1:1000) {

    temp2 <- sample(df$serving, size=50, replace=FALSE)
    #descdist(temp2, boot = 1000)
    fw <- fitdist(temp2, "weibull")
    fg <- fitdist(temp2, "gamma")
    fln <- fitdist(temp2, "lnorm")
    gof <- gofstat(list(fw, fg, fln), fitnames = c("weibull", "gamma", "lnorm"))$chisqpvalue

    if(i == 1) { results <- gof }
    if(i > 1) { results <- rbind(results, gof) }

}

row.names(results) <- c(1:nrow(results))
results <- as.data.frame(results)
summary(results)

 weibull              gamma               lnorm         
Min.   :0.0000000   Min.   :0.0000000   Min.   :0.000000  
1st Qu.:0.0000001   1st Qu.:0.0000001   1st Qu.:0.000000  
Median :0.0009940   Median :0.0035025   Median :0.003264  
Mean   :0.0380086   Mean   :0.0519209   Mean   :0.058692  
3rd Qu.:0.0383365   3rd Qu.:0.0578076   3rd Qu.:0.056701  
Max.   :0.7309149   Max.   :0.8963196   Max.   :0.855437
```

Comment: I am not sure (but it seems to be pretty close) - what is each row 1:10 and why 10 rows? I have added to my original question. As I understand what you have done - take a sample of 50 from groundbeef and run 1000 times against each distribution to provide a p value from gof.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment about 10 etc.

Comment: Yeah so I've taken a random sample of 50 withough replacement from the original 254, then bootstrapped the gof on the random sample 1000 times, each row 1:10 is a single bootstrap estimate. Do you actually want to bootstrap the random sample or just randomly sample a given size N numerous times?

Comment: If I'm following you correctly then the `summary` I've added is what you're looking for.

Comment: "randomly sample a given size N numerous times" - as mentioned, if the sample is 1 it will not fit the distribution well (and will be indicated by p value p> .05). please correct me if that makes no sense.

Comment: It wont work for a sample size of 1 as there'd be no distribution. See changes made to the answer, is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: I am getting 'Error: could not find function "data.table"'

Comment: I changed that to `as.data.frame` earlier. I habitually use data.table which needs the data.table package.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95101/discussion-between-user1222447-and-n311v).